# ¿Por qué no me devuelve la data del json?

Tags: javascript, json, jsp, jquery-ui, autocompletar

Estoy trabajando con el 'ui autocomplete' por categorías, los datos se envían con normalidad y la 'query' se ejecuta sin problemas, pero en el buscador no me retorna la 'data' del 'json'... ¿qué es lo que estoy haciendo mal y cómo puedo solucionarlo?

```js
<%@ include file="../conectadb.jsp" %>
<%@ page language="java"%>
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.01 Transitional//EN"     "http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/loose.dtd">
<html>
<head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=ISO-8859-1">
<title>Basic Search</title>
<style type="text/css">
    .ui-autocomplete-category {
    font-weight: bold;
    padding: .2em .4em;
    margin: .8em 0 .2em;
    line-height: 1.5;
  }
</style>
 <link rel="stylesheet" href="http://code.jquery.com/ui/1.10.3/themes/smoothness/jquery-ui.css" />
        <script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.9.1.js"></script>
        <script src="http://code.jquery.com/ui/1.10.3/jquery-ui.js"></script>
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="/resources/demos/style.css" />

</head>
<body>

<script>
      $.widget("custom.catcomplete", $.ui.autocomplete, {
                _renderMenu : function(ul, items) {
                    var that = this, currentCategory = "";
                    $.each(items, function(index, item) {
                        if (item.category != currentCategory) {
                            ul.append("<li class='ui-autocomplete-category'>" + item.category + "</li>");
                            currentCategory = item.category;
                        }
                        that._renderItemData(ul, item);
                    });
                }
            });
</script>

<script type="text/javascript">
    $(function() {
    $( "#search" ).catcomplete({
        delay: 0,
        minLength: 3,
        source: function(request, response) {
        $.ajax({
         url : "getsearchjson.jsp",
         dataType : "json",
         data :"searchText=eric",
         success : function(data) {
            console.log(data);
      
                            } //success
                        });
    }
});
});
</script>

<p />

<div class="container well">
    <div class="row-fluid">
        <form action="search" method="get">
            <div class="input-append">
                <input type="text" name="query" id="search" placeholder="Search.."/>
                
            </div>

        </form>
    </div>
</div>

</body>
</html>
```

```html
<%@ include file="../conectadb.jsp" %>
<% 
   response.setContentType("application/json");
    String term=request.getParameter("searchText");   
    
%>
[
<%
  COMANDO =   "SELECT ID, "+
       "ORDEN, "+
       "NOMBRE GRUPO, "+
       "CODIGO, "+
       "NOM_SERV(ID_SERVICIO) SERVICIO, "+
       "ID_SERVICIO "+
       "FROM CATALOGO_NIVEL"+
      "WHERE    (NOMBRE LIKE UPPER ('%"+term+"%') OR ID_SERVICIO = '"+term+"') ";
  rset = stmt.executeQuery(COMANDO);
  while(rset.next() ){
%>
    { label: "<%=rset.getString("SERVICIO")%>", category: "<%=rset.getString("GRUPO")%>"},
<%}%>    
     {label:"", category:""}

];
```

Comment: Hola Julio! ¿Si haces un `console.log(data)` dentro del `success` te pinta los resultados esperados?

Comment: No, no pinta nada

Answer (score 0):

Mmm, entiendo que `getsearchjson.jsp` hace referencia al primer bloque de código de tu pregunta. De ser así, y si dices que la consulta va bien, creo que lo que te faltaría sería devolver los valores de la consulta.

Al final de `getsearchjson.jsp` deberías incluir los resultados de la consulta al objeto `response` y hacerle un `flush()` para devolver los resultados. Según como lo tienes ahora mismo, haces la llamada se ejecuta la consulta pero al no incluirse en el objeto response, estos se pierden.

Ademas, mencionar que en mi opinión no es muy buena practica hacer consultas a BBDD directamente desde un `jsp`, deberías tener un `Servlet` al cual se hicieran las peticiones y ahí realizas todas las operaciones logicas que necesites para esa `request`.

Te modifico un poco el código y me dices si te funciona.

```
<%@ include file="../conectadb.jsp" %>
<% 
   response.setContentType("application/json");
   response.setCharacterEncoding("UTF-8");
//En este objeto deberías incluir todos los valores que quieras que te devuelva una petición AJAX
   PrintWriter writer = response.getWriter();
   String term=request.getParameter("searchText");   

  String results="";
  String COMANDO =   "SELECT ID, "+
       "ORDEN, "+
       "NOMBRE GRUPO, "+
       "CODIGO, "+
       "NOM_SERV(ID_SERVICIO) SERVICIO, "+
       "ID_SERVICIO "+
       "FROM CATALOGO_NIVEL"+
      "WHERE    (NOMBRE LIKE UPPER ('%"+term+"%') OR ID_SERVICIO = '"+term+"') ";
  rset = stmt.executeQuery(COMANDO);
  while(rset.next() ){

    results+="{ 'label': '"+rset.getString("SERVICIO")+"', 'category': '"+rset.getString("GRUPO")+"'},"
}    

  writer.println(results);
  writer.flush();

%>
```

**Nota:** Es posible que los datos devueltos no estén en el formato correcto para el `ui.autocomplete` de momento, con que la petición `ajax` devuelva algo estamos por el buen camino.

**UPDATE**

Como te dije, te pongo un ejemplo sencillito de Servlet

```
package tu.propio.paquete;

public class ExampleServlet extends HttpServlet {

    //Tus peticiones tipo POST entraran por aqui
    @Override
    protected void doPost(HttpServletRequest req, HttpServletResponse resp) throws ServletException, IOException {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        super.doPost(req, resp);
    }


    //Tus peticiones tipo GET entraran por aquí
    @Override
    protected void doGet(HttpServletRequest req, HttpServletResponse resp) throws ServletException, IOException {
        response.setContentType("application/json");
        response.setCharacterEncoding("UTF-8");
        //En este objeto deberías incluir todos los valores que quieras que 
        te devuelva una petición AJAX
        PrintWriter writer = response.getWriter();
        String term=request.getParameter("searchText");   

        String results="";
        String COMANDO =   "SELECT ID, "+
                "ORDEN, "+
                "NOMBRE GRUPO, "+
                "CODIGO, "+
                "NOM_SERV(ID_SERVICIO) SERVICIO, "+
                "ID_SERVICIO "+
                "FROM CATALOGO_NIVEL"+
                "WHERE    (NOMBRE LIKE UPPER ('%"+term+"%') OR ID_SERVICIO = 
                '"+term+"') ";
        rset = stmt.executeQuery(COMANDO);
        while(rset.next() ){

          results+="{ 'label': '"+rset.getString("SERVICIO")+"', 'category': 
          '"+rset.getString("GRUPO")+"'},"
        }    

        writer.println(results);
        writer.flush();
    }  
}
```

Al crearte un `servlet`, también deberás declararlo en el `web.xml` de tu proyecto :

```
<servlet>
    <servlet-name>exampleServlet</servlet-name>
    <servlet-class>tu.propio.paquete.ExampleServlet</servlet-class>
  </servlet>
  <servlet-mapping>
    <servlet-name>exampleServlet</servlet-name>
    <url-pattern>/exampleServlet</url-pattern>
  </servlet-mapping>
```

Y tu petición ajax, deberías cambiar el parámetro `url` por el nombre del servlet

```
$.ajax({
     url : "getsearchjson.jsp",
     dataType : "json",
     data :"exampleServlet",
     success : function(data) {
          console.log(data);
     } //success
});
```

Comment: aun no retorna ningún dato en el buscador

Comment: Hola Julio, el problema como te he dicho antes es que un `jsp` no devuelve valores, un `jsp` no deja de ser una pagina que procesada por el servidor, devuelve una plantilla de HTML al final. Tienes que crearte un `Servlet` y hacer todas las peticiones a ese `Servlet` y desde ahí, realizar las operaciones a BBDD pertinentes y devolver el jsp con los valores que necesites.